# Internal Server Error when response text from ajax POST call is big

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, json

I am using an ajax call like the following:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'frmHistoryReportFinal.aspx/GetDataTable',
        data: json_data,
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (responseText) {

            if (responseText.d == "")
                return;
            parsedData = JSON.parse(responseText.d);

            alert(parsedData);

            count = 0;


        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //process the error
            alert(xhr);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

When I have a small set of data returned from my C# codebehind. The ajax call functions well. But when I have a json string with larger data, say 200 records returned then the ajax call gives error("Internal Server Error"). 
Please help me resolve the issue as I usually need to handle large datasets.

Comment: `Internal Server Error` means something fails on the serverside, there's nothing we can do to tell you what is failing on the server by looking at the clientside code you've posted ?

Comment: its server side error, you should see server log message

Comment: If your json is larger than 4 mb then you need to adjust `httpRuntime maxRequestLength` in web.config

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27171576/492258)