# Upload file more than 4GB by jquery to asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, upload

Im working on an asp mvc application . In my application I want to upload file more that 4GB or 5 GB to server side but jquery cant upload more that 6MG .
Thanks any one who help me!

above code are for the application

Comment: this is my web.config
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="45096"  targetFramework="4.5" />
  . . . .
 <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

Answer (score 0):

this settings for 1GB, you can adjust value upon your request in web config

```
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    ...

<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
```

`maxRequestLength` is in KB
`maxAllowedContentLength` is in Byte

Comment: maxAllowedContentLength is uint in bytes, it cannot be larger than 4GB